# What is the "inname" parameter to the /tags 2.0 API?

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, documentation, parameters

I'm just playing with the new 2.0 API and [in /tags there is a field `inname`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags) that I can't find any description or documentation for.

What does it do? Is it like the old `filter` parameter on the old API?

---

**Update:** Now that I have the answer I've retagged this as a bug, meaning an omission from the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inname` has been documented on [`/users`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users) and [`/tags`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags) now.  Thanks for catching that oversight.

Comment: No problem. It has a spelling mistake though: "The inname parameter **let's** a consumer filter down to tags that contain a certain substring". "Let's" is a contraction of "let us" - you should use plain "lets" here.

Comment: @hippietrail - typos will be fixed (there's on in /users too) with the next build.

Answer (score 1):

`inname` limits the returned items to only those that contain the specified value. This parameter is identical to the `filter` parameter in v1.0 and v1.1 of the API.

Note: this parameter is also present in the `/users` route.

Comment: Thanks. Should I tag this as "bug report" with the bug being an omission from the documentation?

Comment: Sure, that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The `inname` parameter restricts the results of a name search to only those that contain the specified substring. The following methods support it:

- [`/badges`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges)
- [`/badges/name`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-by-name)
- [`/badges/tags`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-by-tag)
- [`/users`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users)
- [`/tags`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags)
- [`/tags/required`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/required-tags)
- [`/tags/moderator-only`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/moderator-only-tags)

filtering on badge, user, or tag names, as applicable.